# Changing/Adding Resource Dictionary in code behind, Please help

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, resourcedictionary

I'm am currently developing a silverlight application, I am still a beginner with this.
I am wondering if it is possible to change the resource dictionary's source in code behind(C#)
within the App.xaml?
I have tried the code below, but get an exception, i am getting the style folder name from a WCF Service, the variable is called Style(this contains the name of the folder)

```
ResourceDictionary rDictionary = this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0];
        rDictionary.Source = new Uri(string.Format("Resources/Styles/{0}/Styles.xaml", style), UriKind.Relative);
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rDictionary);
```

I'm getting an error at

```
rDictionary.Source = new Uri(string.Format("Resources/{0}/Styles.xaml", "Default"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Which reads

```
System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, String s)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
   at FCStarFish.App..ctor()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="resourcestyles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary /> <!-- Dummy, this is the one we will replace -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Then we place a ResourceDictionary in [0] (where our dummy ResourceDictionary is).

Load or replace the style dictionary (load it with the default style in Application_Startup in app.xaml.cs)

```
var rDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
rDictionary.Source = new Uri(string.Format("/MyApp;component/Resources/Styles/{0}/Styles.xaml", style), UriKind.Relative);
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] = rDictionary;
```

Replace MyApp with your applications name.

Answer (score 1):

First follow the steps mentioned by NateTheGreat below and prepend your UriStirng with "/". It should look like:

```
ResourceDictionary rDictionary = this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0];
        rDictionary.Source = new Uri(string.Format("/Resources/Styles/{0}/Styles.xaml", style), UriKind.Relative);
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem.  In my case, the solution was to change the resource dictionary XAML file's build action to "Content", Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer", and Custom Tool to an empty string.  The defaults were set to Page/Do not copy/MSBuild:Compile, respectively.